# How do I run boxen in Mavericks with rbenv installed?

Tags: ruby, rbenv, osx-mavericks, boxen

I recently upgraded to Mac OS 10.9 and now I get this message when I run boxen:

> Bundler is not compatible with Ruby 2.0 or Rubygems 2.0. Please
>   upgrade to Bundler 1.3 or higher. Can't bootstrap, dependencies are
>   outdated

I imagined that I could just set boxen's `.ruby-version` file to something like 1.8.7, but based on the message above, it still seems to be using Ruby 2.0.

How can I run boxen in Mavericks?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ran into the exact same issue. The answer is actually deceptively simple. Since Mavericks now includes Ruby 2.0.0p247 and Rubygems 2.0.3, and you apparently upgraded, your system ruby will not find your bundler or ansi gems. So what you need to do is install both with your system ruby, as root.

```
sudo /usr/bin/gem install bundler
sudo /usr/bin/gem install ansi
```

Then just restart or terminal. You can now run `boxen` as you would normally. Also, in order not to keep old files lying around, you may want to cleanup `/Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/` because it will include your old installation of both bundler and ansi on a ruby and gem installation you no longer have.

Comment: You can also just run the `boxen` command from your home directory. It will ask for a sudo password and install system bundler.

Answer (score 0):

Seems the problem is with bundler. Just try to update it.

```
gem install bundler
```

Answer (score 0):

system ruby (now 2.0) needed an updated version of bundler. Currently, only a pre-release version is compatible with Mac OS 10.9. If `gem install bundler` complains that you need a newer version of Bundler, as above, try `gem install bundler --pre`. Also, you may need elevated privileges to install gems for your system's ruby.

I am still confused about why Boxen wants to use system ruby's bundler gem when a different ruby installation is defined by Boxen's rbenv config, but the problem has a working solution now.